# Could a coronal mass ejection be responsible for this?

Tags: solar-wind

Around 9pm (GMT) on June 9th, we noticed that the two security cameras had gone dark. Around the same time, a photo voltaic sensor responsible for keeping the yard lights on at night also failed.

In the morning the cameras were back to normal, which means that only the LEDs, responsible for night vision on the cameras, had failed. The cameras are powered by a 12V/2A power supply, which makes it even less likely that a power surge is responsible for the LEDs (and only the LEDs) burning out.

Checking upon the space weather, I noticed that there was a solar flare (M5.9) emitted right around this time. I don't know much about solar flares, but from what I gather M5.9 is on the very low end of things.

**Could this be the reason 2 cameras and one photo voltaic sensor failed at the same time?** Or what else should I look into?

*Mods, sorry if the question is somewhat open ended. Feel free to close the question if not appropriate.*

Comment: Seems unduly speculative and far too localized.

Answer (score 3):

It is very unlikely that that solar flare had anything to do with your equipment failures. It takes days for coronal mass ejections (which are what can cause geomagnetic storms) to transit from the Sun to the Earth.

If you check the [magnetic storms online](http://www.tesis.lebedev.ru/en/magnetic_storms.html) website you can see there wasn't any notable magnetic storm activity on the 9th.

I would look for a cause closer to home like someone hitting a power pole and causing an electrical surge. And invest in a surge protector or a UPS for your equipment.

Comment: I would have thought about a power surge, especially because I am in a 3rd world country. But the photo voltaic sensor is not subject to spikes since it doesn't draw from the electrical grid, correct?

Comment: The sensor probably does interface with grid power. A sensor has to connect to the equipment it is being used for so there is very probably an electrical connection and it is probably actually powered by the equipment it is connected to. Sensors usually aren't self powered.

Comment: Yes I knew it was connected, but I was under the impression it would be a self-powered relay.

Comment: But what about a mass ejection that happened earlier in the week?

Comment: Also note, the cameras are powered by a 12V/2A power supply, which makes it even less likely that a power surge is responsible for the LEDs (and only the LEDs) burning out.